# Chef, how to set the multiple same values with different attributes?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

In one local node, using chef-solo. I want set 3 value "server", but only the last value set. Please, advise, how set all values?
I want to achieve, this result in settings.xml:

```
<servers> 
  <server> 
    <id>server1</id> 
    <username>user1</username>
     <password>pass1</password>
  </server> 
  <server>
     <id>server2</id>
     <username>user2</username>
     <password>pass2</password>
  </server> 
  <server>
     <id>server3</id> 
     <username>user3</username>
     <password>pass3</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

This is my cookbook:

```
chef_gem 'nori' do
  action :install
end

chef_gem 'gyoku' do
  action :install
end

include_recipe "maven"
node.default['maven']['version'] = "3.3.3"

maven_settings "settings.servers" do
  value "server" => {
    "id" => "server1",
    "username" => "user1",
    "password" => "pass1"
  }
end

maven_settings "settings.servers" do
  value "server" => {
    "id" => "server2",
    "username" => "user2",
    "password" => "pass2"
  }
end

maven_settings "settings.servers" do
  value "server" => {
    "id" => "server3",
    "username" => "user3",
    "password" => "pass3"
  }
end
```

Thanks, foy any advise !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and to Chef. It is unclear, to me, what you want to achieve. Please describe more in detail. Is this, how your recipe looks like? You can't declare three resources `maven_settings[settings.servers]` for the same node. Are you familiar with the [attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) concept of Chef?

Comment: Yes - just like [StephenKing](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400222/stephenking) says, the 3 different resources shouldn't have the same name, so you can simply try giving them a different name. 
I'm also not sure wht you're trying to achieve, but changing the "settings.servers" to - for example - "settings.server1", "settings.server2", "settings.server3" should solve your current problem with the value attribute.

Comment: Thanks, for your answers ! I edited the first message, added what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to edit the `servers` xml attribute, so according to the [maven cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/maven) README, the syntax should be like this:

```
maven_settings "settings" do
    value "servers" => {
      "server1" => {
        "id" => "server1",
        "username" => "user1",
        "password" => "pass1"
      },
      "server2" => {
        "id" => "server2",
        "username" => "user2",
        "password" => "pass2"
      },
      "server3" => {
        "id" => "server3",
        "username" => "user3",
        "password" => "pass3"
      }   
}
end
```

Comment: It turns something like this: <servers> & lt; server & gt; & lt; i & gt; server 1 & lt; / id & gt; & lt; username & gt; user1 & lt; / username & gt; & lt; password & gt; pass1 & lt; / password & gt; & lt; / server & gt; </ servers>

Comment: Hmm... ok I see... I've edited my answer above accordingly. Please try this, as that worked for me.

Comment: Big thank you for your help! I think that such an option should work, but I have done with "From file" option. I'm not sure, what record "server1,serverN" in settings.xml will work properly.